# Make someone join to a voice channel Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This question can be weird, but I want that if a person types: `!(something)` makes him join to an specific channel, and also if its possible to me to make someone else join voice chat when he is not in voice chat!

Would appreciate to set that up in this code:

```js
const discord = require("discord.js")
const config = require('../config.json')

module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args) => {
  // Logic...
}

module.exports.help = {
  name: 'tour'
}
```

I would appreciate a lot your help, thank you!

Comment: No, you can't force a user to join a voice channel

Comment: The Discord API doesn't allow that and in general you can't simply force someone to join in a channel without their willing

Comment: what about a command the person "A" types !(something) and he gets to join a specific channel, where i assume he is willing to, because he is using the command, right? ty

Comment: The API does not let you. Period.

Comment: How would you feel if for example someone made a bot to force you into a voice channel 24/7 and basically spy on you through it?

Comment: i dont mean  "A" forces "B" to connect, i want is "A" uses a command, and A goes to a voice channel, is for bussiness, to make them go to the channel where their product is, clear?

Answer (score 2):

No, Discord itself makes it impossible to pull someone into a Voice Channel like this.

What you can do, however, is let them join a waiting room voicechannel before and then move them into a different one on demand. If this is viable for you depends on what you actually want to accomplish, though.

Comment: thats what i actually need to, i need this for business, need that when he does a command he goes to a channel where he can talk with the ones he needs, for example, im ryan so, i use !pizza and PAM it will make me join to PIZZA where he will be have his attention for the product he wants,